# Will a view controller in a navigation controller keep running even if it is not the top view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController, whose view controller stack contains two view controllers, A and B, where B is the top most view controller.

My NSTimer in A is firing periodically. My question is that is the timer in A guaranteed to keep working when B is shown? Is there any situations where the timer will stop, for example, what happens if B receives a memory warning?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes OfCourse your timer will be running from the time its **fired**, unless you write any conditions to **invalidate** it.
- You can't do anything for pertaining to memory warning, instead you avoid it.
- You may invalidate the timer at 'ViewWillDisappear' if you don't want to continue after pushing to B viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your timer is initialized/scheduled. If it is a member variable of A, it will be unloaded when A is unloaded--see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026723/keeping-a-timer-running-on-another-page-when-navigating-around).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll do some experiments on it